how to repent from a Lie
before I started to become a practicing muslim I lied to my friends and told them I wasn’t a virgin because I feared they would look of me as less than them if I was the only virgin one, how do I repent from this lie do I have to confess and tell them it was a lie or can I just repent to allah?

Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and the SE model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help].

assalam alaikom
To repent for this lie, you do not need to confess to your friends. Repenting to Allah is sufficient, as long as you follow these steps:
Feel regret for the lie you told.
Ask Allah for forgiveness with sincerity, saying something like:
"O Allah, forgive me for the lie I told. I repent and seek Your pardon."
Make a firm intention not to lie again in the future.
If the lie caused harm to others (e.g., impacting relationships or trust), try to make things right by correcting any misunderstandings if necessary. But if the lie didn’t cause harm, just focus on seeking forgiveness.
Repenting sincerely to Allah will cleanse you from this sin, and Allah is the Most Forgiving. No need to confess to your friends unless you feel it is necessary to restore trust.
May Allah accept your repentance and guide you on the right path.
ALLAH KNOW BEST
